# Running EXPECT_THROW inside a for loop in googletest framework

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

I am trying to create an array of strings that is needed for running a test. This is how I am doing it.

```
TEST(ParseTest, UnknownType) {
    String test_strings[] = {
        String("X 1024\n"),
        String("AB 1024\n")
    };

    int test_strings_size = sizeof(test_strings) / sizeof(test_strings[0]);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < test_strings_size; idx++) {
        Transaction transaction;
        String transaction_type = test_strings[idx];
        EXPECT_THROW(transaction.parse(transaction_type), ParseError);
    }
}
```

But when I run this in google test framework, I get the following error:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from ParseTest
[ RUN      ] ParseTest.UnknownRequestType
tests/transaction.cpp:20: Failure
Expected: transaction.parse(transaction_type) throws an exception of type ParseError.
  Actual: it throws nothing.
[  FAILED  ] ParseTest.UnknownRequestType (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from ParseTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] ParseTest.UnknownRequestType

 1 FAILED TEST
```

When this should actually run two test cases, it complains of only one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Here is some clarification:

You are actually running one test case, see the following definition:

```
TEST(TestCase, TestName)
```

So in the test result when it says "1 test from 1 test case ran", 'test' refers to your TestName field (in your case UnknownType) and test case refers obviously to 'test case' (ParseTest). It doesn't matter how many 'ASSERTions' or 'EXPECTations' you set inside a specific test. It will be eventually reported as one test.

So if you have

```
TEST(TestCase1, Test1){
    .....
}
TEST(TestCase1, Test2){
    ....
}
```

it will be reported as: 2 tests from 1 test case ran

So, assuming that "X 1024" is the one that will cause the exception, I suspect that the result of "AB 1024" (no exception) is the one eventually reported.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a [value parameterized test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/V1_7_AdvancedGuide.md#value-parameterized-tests) to get more convenient test results.

Example:

```
class ParseTest : public ::testing::TestWithParam<const String> {};

TEST_P(ParseTest, UnknownType)
{
    Transaction transaction;
    String transaction_type = GetParam();
    EXPECT_THROW(transaction.parse(transaction_type), ParseError);
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(UnknownTypeInstance,
                        ParseTest,
                        ::testing::Values(String("X 1024\n"), String("AB 1024\n")));
```